# How to use to_date for date like '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0'

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert text '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0' into date by using to_date but I am not getting which format shoud I use.

If you check some examples like :
to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
which works fine but in my case I am unable to find such a format.

Could you please help which date format should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `to_date()` with your string as it is, because the `.0` part represents milliseconds - and Oracle's date data type does not have millisecond precision:

```
select to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:01.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

select to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:01.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;

ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

That error is because the `FF` part of the model doesn't apply for dates.

You can convert to a timestamp:

```
select to_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:01.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-0
-----------------------
1970-01-01 00:00:01.000
```

and then if you really do only want it as a date, cast that to be a date:

```
select cast(to_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:01.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as date) from dual;

CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('
-------------------
1970-01-01 00:00:01
```

Or you could use string manipulation to remove the fractional seconds part before using `to_date()`, or <strike>if it it always going to be `.0` - with no variation -</strike> you could treat that as a constant part of the format model [as @mathguy has already shown].

Also notice that the value you have could be treated as a timestamp literal, but only if the whole thing is a fixed value:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:01.0' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'1970-01-0100:
-----------------------
1970-01-01 00:00:01.000
```

and again you could cast that to a date if needed.

Comment: "with no variation" is incorrect. The ".0" in the format model will handle .9 in the input without issues. I already said, if the input may have .309 then ".000000000" in the format model will handle that too.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, not sure why it allows that. Well, I've already referred out to your answer.

Comment: I was surprised when I found that out (by experimentation - someone, perhaps the same poster, perhaps someone else, asked the same thing on OTN a few days ago: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4270079). I assume Oracle did that exactly for this use case!

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to convert to date, or to timestamp?

If you need to convert to date, and ignore the fractional seconds, you can use the boilerplate format element in the date format model.

```
to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:01.0','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS".0"')
```

Notice what I added: a string in **double** quotes, namely `.0`. This will mask any decimal digit, not just 0 (but it must be a digit).

If some inputs may have more decimal places, you can expand the boilerplate text, for example to ".000000000"  If there are "too many zeros" in the format model (compared to the input), that will work; but if there are too few, it won't.